# Get only categories from a specific custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to get categories from a specific post type : `member` .

### I am using this code

```
<?php
    $taxonomy = 'category';
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

But the problem is : when i am adding a category to `member` then it is also added to `post type : post` and when deleted it also deleted from both post type.
What can i do now?

Comment: The function `get_terms` is fine for your purpose

Comment: [Adding Categories And Post Tags Boxes For Custom Post Type In WordPress](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/07/custom-post-type-with-categories-post.html) or this plugin: [Add Tags And Category To Page and Post Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-tags-and-category-to-page/). If you look to the code of the plugin, you will find some answers…

Answer (score 0):

try this way this will display categories from specific post and retrieve the terms for a post.

```
<?php
$postArg = array('post_type'=>'post',
                        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
                        'order'=>'desc',
                      );

        $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
        global $post;
        if($getPost->have_posts()){
            echo '<ul>';
                while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post();

                    echo "<h2>".$post->post_title."</h2>";
                    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category' );
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo "<li>".$term_name = $term->name.'</li>';
                    }
                endwhile;
            echo '</ul>';
        }

?>
```

**Second way**

```
<?php 

$category = get_terms('category');//custom category name 

foreach ($category as $catVal) {
    echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>'; 
 }
?>
```